# Scala + pass function and another value as arguments

Tags: scala, function

In my scala code, I have a helper class that sets SparkSession like below:

```
  def withSpark(func: SparkSession => Unit): Unit = {
    val session = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("temp checks")
      .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
      .getOrCreate()
    session.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))

    try {
      func(session)
    } finally {
      session.stop()
      System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port")
    }
  }
```

I'm using this util in my main code like this:

```
withSpark {
    session => <do required stuff here> 
}
```

The `withSpark` function by default sets master to `local[*]` every time. I want to change this based on environment as `local[*]`/`yarn`/`spark_master_URL`.

For this, I want to change `withSpark` code something like below:

```
  def withSpark(func: SparkSession => Unit, spark_master: String): Unit = {
    val session = SparkSession.builder()
      .master(spark_master)
      .appName("temp checks")
      .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
      .getOrCreate()
    session.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))

    try {
      func(session)
    } finally {
      session.stop()
      System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port")
    }
  }
```

and main code like :

```
withSpark("yarn") {
    session => <do required stuff here> 
}
```

But, I'm unable to do this. Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you expect such declaration to work like you wanted? Also, this is basic syntax, if you are going to be using **Spark** at least try to learn the basis of **Scala**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiple parameter lists](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html) can be used to provide such syntax

```
def withSpark(spark_master: String)(func: SparkSession => Unit) = ???
```

Note how function is in the **last** parameter list. Now we can express

```
withSpark("yarn") {
    session => <do required stuff here> 
}
```